# SSIS - Modify date column from the 15th to the 1st of the month

Tags: sql-server, excel, visual-studio-2008, ssis

```
SELECT * FROM [MarkTSK] 
WHERE [MonthlyDt] IS NOT NULL
--AND
--SELECT DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,getdate()), 0)
```

Hello folks. Does anyone know how to correctly write this statement to 
display the FIRST of each month? I have an Excel file that I am importing
into a Server  using MS SSIS (VisualStudio 2008). The dates are monthly, but the last few months were the 15th June, May, April etc. My intent is to make 
all of them show 1st of the month. All the months before January 2015 have been on the 1st of the month.

The SQL Query above is what I wrote in the Excel source Editor.

Thank You

Comment: `DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(MonthlyDt)-1),MonthlyDt)`

Comment: It would help if you listed several dates along with the intended result of the query, ie, before and after scenario.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT *, DATEADD('d',-DAY([MonthlyDT])+1, [Date])  AS [MonthD]
FROM [MarkTSK] 

WHERE [MonthlyDT] IS NOT NULL
```

Thank you everyone. The SCRIPT above worked for me. All the dates that were not on the 1st of the month, now shows as the 1st.

Answer (score 1):

This should always give you the first of the current Month

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE()),0)
```

to pull back the first of the month for dates in your table something like this should do it

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,[MonthlyDt]),0) FROM [MarkTSK] 
WHERE [MonthlyDt] IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thank you JRadich. I have months back to the beginning of the year; so the query would have to account for those ones too

Comment: You have a list of dates in a spreadsheet and want to use a SQL query to find the first of the month for that date, correct?

Comment: That is correct. Actually, I have dates back to 2 years (on a monthly basis). They ALL show the 1st of the month, but since January, I have been getting the 15th of the month. My intent is to change it back to the 1st when I import the data

Comment: Replace `GETDATE()` in the above, with any date and it will return the first of the month for the supplied date

Comment: The idea is to let it run dynamically, rather than doing a SELECT statement individually. This statement goes inside the Excel Editor

Comment: So the updated answer is not what you are looking for?

Comment: No, not Update. I am simply planning to select the dataset while making sure the [MonthlyDt] column shows the 1st instead of any other date

Comment: I meant the update the answer above not and UPDATE SQL statment

Answer (score -1):

Use [DatePart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to extract the Month and Year adding in the day manually.
Something like:

```
SELECT Convert(date, DatePart('yyyy', [MonthlyDt]) + DatePart('mm', [MonthlyDt]) + '01' ) FROM [MarkTSK] 
WHERE [MarkTSK] IS NOT NULL
```

(Disclaimer: untested code)

Comment: Thank you. I am getting an error message - Error at Data Flow Task [Excel Source[1]]: No column information was returned by the SQL command.

Comment: Even though you didn't test this, what was your chain of thought? How did you end up with this? If `MonthlyDt` is not null, then tearing it to pieces and then putting the pieces back together (replacing the day part with `01` along the way) will result in a date that isn't null either. If `MonthlyDt` *is* null, then doing those same operations will give you null. Your suggestion, therefore, will give *exactly* the same result as the OP's current code.

Comment: Anyway, the OP isn't *looking for* the first of a month. I at first thought he was, too, but then I re-read the title. The OP wants to *modify the returned date values*, changing every date to the first of the same month.

Comment: @AndriyM I was under the impression the OP was looking to modify each month to the 1st, as in May 15th to May 1st, March 18 to March 1st as he said "to display the FIRST of each month?" If that isn't the intent, I would suggest the answer be re-written to be more clear. I'll delete this answer in a bit so it doesn't confuse anyone.

Comment: Yes, the goal is to change to 1st, as the OP has just confirmed, but change for the purpose of returning the changed date in the output. You are building your changed dates in the WHERE clause – that will have no effect on the output.

Comment: Err, that was supposed to be in the select, not the where clause.